# Angular : How can I increment and decrement a value in loop?

Tags: angular

I want to increment and decrement a value in loop Angular.

---

For Example : **Quotes**

I want to show the Quotes and show **Quotation number** like this :

**1**. <- That's what I want

**2**. <- That's what I want

So this is **quotes.component.ts** for send request to server :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import {Quote} from "../quote.interface";
import {QuoteService} from "../quote.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-quotes',
    templateUrl: './quotes.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./quotes.component.css']
})
export class QuotesComponent implements OnInit {
    quotes:Quote[];
    loading = false;

    constructor(private quoteService:QuoteService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }


    onGetQuotes() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.quoteService.getQuotes()
            .subscribe(
                (quotes:Quote[]) => this.quotes = quotes,
                (error:Response) =>console.log(error),
                (loading:Response) => this.loading = false
            );

    }


}
```

And my **quote.component.html** for show the loop :

```
<div class="card mt-3" id="">
  <div class="card-header">
    {{ num ++ }}  |  {{ quote.content }}
  </div>

  <div class="card-footer">
    <div *ngIf="editing">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="editValue">
      <a href="#" (click)="onUpdate()">Save</a>
      <a href="#" (click)="onCancel()">Cancel</a>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!editing">
      <a href="#" (click)="onEdit()">Edit</a>
      <a href="#" (click)="onDelete()">Delete</a>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

As you see i wrote `{{ num ++ }}`

like `PHP code`
    But its gave me error !

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>
> Parser Error: Unexpected end of expression

How can i figure it out ?

Comment: oh sorry i was Define 'Num' to '0'

Comment: So you solved the issue ?

Comment: there should be ngFor somewhere if you want to display it repeatedly, i dont see it, can you show parent component where you are using this

Comment: Where is your loop? From Where comes this "num" ?

Comment: increment operator is not allowed in interpolation

Comment: @distante i was Defined the 'Num' to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For information you cannot do `++`

JavaScript expressions that have or promote side effects are prohibited, including:

- assignments (=, +=, -=, ...)
- new
- chaining expressions with ; or ,
- increment and decrement operators (++ and --)

Check here : https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-expressions

---

if you want to display something repeatedly, then you should use `*ngFor`, in that there is index so you should use like this

```
 <div class="row" *ngFor="let a of array; let i = index;">
            <div class="col-md-1">
              {{i + 1}}
            </div>
...rest of code
</div>
```

Comment: i am using angular cli .. i cant use *ngFor in my Quote.component.html file ~!

Comment: @Ben_Rmb - angular cli has to do nothing with angular code you are doing

Comment: @Ben_Rmb Angular cli is a command line interface to scaffold and build angular apps.